# How to fetch nested data from json in JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I have to fetch data from https://photon.komoot.io/api?q=britain&osm_tag=tourism:hotel I only need to get the name and state from the properties list. Trouble is, it's nested and I don't know how to get data from nested JSON files. Can anyone help or give some headers on how I need to proceed? This is my code as of now.
Thanks

```js
fetch("https://photon.komoot.io/api?q=oman&osm_tag=tourism:hotel")
                    .then(data => data.json())
                        .then(data => {
                        let items = [];
                        data.forEach(item => {
                        items.push({ name: item.properties.name, blank: item.properties.state });
                });
                console.log(items);
    })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the returned JSON looks like? You can simply access nested data like so: `foo.bar.baz`, which returns the property `baz` from the object `bar` which is, in turn a property of the `foo` object.

Comment: `data.features.forEach` instead of `data.forEach`. Everything else seems alright

Comment: @blex Thanks a ton blex, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use destructuring to do it.
Will be more readable for you and more clean.

```
let items = [];
items = data.map(d => {
  const { properties: { name, state } } = d;
  return { name, state };
});
```